# How to deal with a PDF that takes CDF data as input? (Metalog distributions)

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, density-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I am trying to utilise the Metalog distribution in a Machine Learning project.

For this project, I need to be able to obtain likelihoods using the PDF of the distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalog_distribution#Probability_density_function

Here is the PDF function, taken from the Wikipedia page above:

$
m_k(y)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
{y(1-y)\over{a_2}}  & \mbox{for } k=2\\
\Bigl({a_2\over{y(1-y)}}+a_3\Bigl({1-y\over{y(1-y)}}+\ln{y\over{1-y}}\Bigr)\Bigr)^{-1} & \mbox{for } k=3\\
\Bigl({a_2\over{y(1-y)}}+a_3\Bigl({1-y\over{y(1-y)}}+\ln{y\over{1-y}}\Bigr)+a_4\Bigr)^{-1} & \mbox{for } k=4\\
\Bigl({1\over{m_{k-1}(y)}}+a_k{k-1\over2}(y-0.5)^{(k-3)/2}\Bigr)^{-1} & \mbox{for odd } k\geq5\\
\Bigl({1\over{m_{k-1}(y)}}+a_k\Bigl({(y-0.5)^{k/2-1}\over{y(1-y)}}+({k\over2}-1)(y-0.5)^{(k/2-2)}\ln{y\over{1-y}}\Bigr)\Bigr)^{-1} & \mbox{for even } k\geq6,\\
\end{array}\right.
$

As we can see, the PDF is written in terms of cumulative probability the $y$ instead of the usual input variable $x$. For fitting I believe I need to compute the Empirical CDF function, e.g. by sorting the data and assigning the $i^{th}$ datapoint the cumulative probability $y=\frac{i}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of datapoints (please correct me if I'm wrong).

But what about new datapoints after the model has been fitted? What is the "proper" way of taking a new datapoint $x$ and computing the probability density $f(x)$? Should I keep the entire training set so I can calculate its new ECDF every time? Should I create a discrete lookup table for $y$ and assign my new value to the closest point?

Or is the Metalog just a poor choice? If so, can anyone recommend a distribution with similar flexibility (the main requirement is to be more flexible than a Beta / Dirichlet distribution)?

Comment: The opening paragraph in the Wikipedia article raises a host of red flags, because it reads like pure marketing hype: much of it is exaggerated, some of it is untrue, and other parts of it extol features that are neither useful nor good (as is evident in the complicated expressions for the PDF in this question).  Whether this distribution family is a good choice for anything depends on the application.  What is yours?

Comment: I have to admit, I got that impression too, especially after watching the author's presentation and reading his paper. Luckily I haven't invested too much time yet. I am doing a university project on calibration of classifier probabilities (making them closer to the true probabilities). The basic idea is to fit a distribution to the scores that the classifier outputs, and then use that to derive a calibration map. Since this was recently done with Beta / Dirichlet distributions, I wanted to try it with a different distribution.

Comment: I should probably point out my supervisor already has some alternative suggestions so that part of the question maybe wasn't so relevant.

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation.  But for us to determine whether anything might be a "poor" choice or to recommend something better, we need to know some details of your data and your objectives.

Comment: Well to be honest the project is more like a learning experience, so there isn't a specific objective or dataset as such, but I appreciate your willingness to help. Mainly I wanted to know whether I was misunderstanding how this Metalog PDF is meant to be used or if that's just how it was designed. Thanks anyway!